# multer won't recognize files with PUT

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, put, multer

So I just installed node and fire up a little HTTP server with express. I'm trying to upload files with `multer` and HTTP `PUT` but it seems as `multer` can't handle PUTting files.

Doing the same thing with `POST` works just fine.

This is my `main.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Up and running');
});

app.put('/up/:file', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('files: ' + req.files);
  console.log(req.params.file);
  res.send('got that');
})

app.post('/up', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('got that');
})

var server = app.listen(8888, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Using `curl` I can `POST` files just fine, e. g. with `curl --form "file=@someFile.jpg" http://localhost:8888/up`.

I tried putting a file with `curl http://localhost:8888/up/someFile.jpg --upload-file someFile.jpg` as well as with `curl -i -T someFile.jpg http://localhost:8888/up/someFile.jpg` but it just won't work. `req.files` is always `undefined`.

---

**Question/TL;DR:** Is multer just not capable of accepting files via `PUT`? How can I receive files per `PUT` with express? Actually, I don't need express ... a plain node solution would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two forms of `curl` for sending your PUT request are not sending `multipart/form-data` bodies, they are sending the raw file contents as the body instead. `multer` does not support that, as it is expecting `multipart/form-data`-encoded forms.

To support these raw file uploads, you will need to handle them yourself (e.g. piping the request to disk or wherever). For example:

```
app.put('/up/:file', function (req, res, next) {
  // TODO: optionally validate `req.headers['content-type']`
  // TODO: sanitize `req.params.file` before
  // using it to create the filename
  var filename = req.params.file;
  var diskStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', filename));
  req.pipe(diskStream).on('finish', function() {
    res.send('got that');
  });
});
```